# Arrows with filled triangle in text

Tags: arrows

the standard arrows in latex are often the curly ones like underneath
\usepackage{extarrows}
But i'd like a more black-filled-triangle kinda arrow
any suggestions?
[image]

the one answer I found here seems pretty complex, almost drawing it by hand. is there an easy package?

Comment: Maybe have a look at the arrows from `mathabx`? They aren't exactly triangles, but more "filled" than the normal ones. If you want real triangles, the `boisik` package has `\rightarrowTriangle`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Ti*k*Z solution that has built-in extensiblity with an optional argument. You can adjust the size and angle of the arrowhead by changing `single arrow head extend` and `single arrow tip angle`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz, amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary {shapes.arrows}

\newcommand{\myarrow}[1][]{\mathrel{\tikz{
    \node[fill, minimum width=.5ex, minimum height=.9em, inner sep=0pt, single arrow, single arrow head extend=2pt, single arrow tip angle=60]
        (A){\raisebox{3.5pt}[0pt][0pt]{$\,\scriptstyle #1\ $}}; \path([xshift=-.4pt]A.west)--(A.east);}}}
\newcommand{\myarrowleft}[1][]{\mathrel{\tikz{
    \node[fill, minimum width=.5ex, minimum height=.9em, inner sep=0pt, single arrow, single arrow head extend=2pt, single arrow tip angle=60, shape border rotate=180]
        (A){\raisebox{3.5pt}[0pt][0pt]{$\ \scriptstyle #1\,$}}; \path(A.west)--([xshift=.4pt]A.east);}}}

\begin{document}

$A\to B\qquad A\xrightarrow{f\circ g}B$

$A\myarrow B\qquad A\myarrow[f\circ g] B$

$A\myarrowleft B\qquad A\myarrowleft[f\circ g] B$

\end{document}
```